# file deletion not working in asp.net vb

Tags: asp.net

I am using following code for file deletion on server after downloading at client site.

The code is working from visual studio but NOT working when website is hosted even on the coding machine.

```
 'To save the word file at temp location with unique name
            Dim varDate As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmmss_fff")

            Dim theFileName As String = Server.MapPath("~/Temp/Report_" & varDate & ".docx")
            oWord.ActiveDocument.SaveAs(theFileName)
            oWord.ActiveDocument.Close()
            oWord.Quit()

Dim filefullname As System.IO.FileInfo = New System.IO.FileInfo(theFileName)
            Response.Clear()
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=Observation_Report.docx")
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", filefullname.Length.ToString())
            Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
            Response.WriteFile(filefullname.FullName)
            Response.Flush()
            System.IO.File.Delete(theFileName)
            Response.End()
```

Comment: Define "not working".  What value is in `theFileName`?  Does that file exist on the server?

Comment: Not working means the file is not deleted..                                 filename details updated in question.

Comment: The file is a word file created on server based on user data.

Comment: do you have read and write rights on the server / folder ?

Comment: It must be issues with the folder rights on the server where your application is hosted

Comment: most probably you dont have write permissions in the folder you are deleting from